# how to convert from probabilty to occupancy grid message

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dears
i am trying to create an occupancy grid message, so for that i have some float data represent the probability,
I used `std_msgs::Float32MultiArray` with `data[]` field =

```
[1.0, 10.0, 0.10000000149011612, 3.0, 9.0, 0.20000000298023224, 3.0, 10.0, 0.1666666716337204, 4.0, 9.0, 0.23333333432674408, 6.0, 8.0, 0.2666666805744171, 6.0, 9.0, 0.03333333507180214]
```

as an example to represent that probability,where the first value `"1.0"` represent the height,  the second value `"10"` represent the width  and the third value represent the probability at that (1.0,10) cell, and so on for other values,
i publish this message and in another node i create `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid grid_message` with these `info`

```
    grid_message.info.height = 20;
    grid_message.info.width = 20;
    grid_message.info.resolution = 0.2;
```

and i use `msg->data[y]*width + msg->data[x]` to fill the `data` field of the `occupancyGrid message`,
for example, at cell(1,10) the corresponding  `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid.data` index is (10*20+1) and in this index i store `0.10000000149011612`
when i  listen to the `occupancyGrid message` the data in `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid.data` look like

```
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 11, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

from where the values `14,5,11,17,2` come from? why these value will not 't be as i filled before publishing them

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363187/how-to-convert-from-probabilty-to-occupancy-grid-message/) by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-11**:
Without the code it might be hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because the data of `OccupancyGrid` is of type `int8`, even if you assign a `float32` type, it does not store the value as it should.

The solution is different depending on the purpose of using `OccupancyGrid`, but for example, the following can be used.
Multiply the data in `std_msgs::Float32MultiArray` by 100, cast it to `int8`, and store it in the OccupancyGrid. Then divide it by 100 at the destination where it will be used.

ref: http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1